Filter Regular Expression Matches with Aspell
I am using Aspell to quickly check to spelling mistakes in a fairly large repository of documents. These documents are written in Asciidoctor *.adoc form.
This means that they can include "special" code-like phrases, terms, and variables (attributes).
What I'd like to be able to do is have an "ignore" filter that does not complain about anything matching the following regex (?<!.):[A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*[^\s]:.*\n -> which basically captures anything that is
\n :[A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]: [A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-] \n #i.e. :aNyth@ng1: aNyth@ng1 
(if regex experts note anything wrong with this expression please feel free to let me know but its tangential).
I am not sure this is even possible with Aspell - if not I'd be happy to take suggestions for a similar "drop in" replacement. It needs to be simple enough to maintain for non-technical document editors to be able to use and add stuff to the dictionary.
Thanks in advance.
